# Strapi Controller Not Populating Nested Repeatable Component

Tags: node.js, next.js, strapi, knex.js

I'm using Strapi v4 and facing an issue with populating a nested repeatable component in my API response. I have a repeatable component `faq_item` inside another component `faqs`. However, when I attempt to populate `faq_item` using the `populate` option in my custom controller, it doesn't return the nested data.

Here's the structure of my components:

- `klubr_house` (collection type)

  - `club_presentation` (dynamiczone )

    - `faqs` ( component)

      - `faq_item` (repeatable component)

And here is my controller's `findOne` method:

```js
"use strict";

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::klubr.klubr", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const entity = await strapi.db.query("api::klubr.klubr").findOne({
      where: { slug: id },
      populate: {
        klubr_house: {
          populate: {
            club_presentation: {
              populate: {
                faqs: {
                  populate: {
                    faq_item: true, // This should populate all fields within each faq_item
                  },
                },
                // ... other fields
              },
            },
            // ... other relations
          },
        },
        // ... other fields
      },
    });
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));
```

Comment: What do you get in the nested response? (empty object, no reach the nested data, etc) Did you tried to type faq_item in plural -> "faq_items"?

Comment: faqs is a component composed of (title + repeatable component called faq_item) in response api I get only the title populated @maxrojas

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the solution

Solution:

I modified the findOne method in my custom controller for the klubr content type. The key was to create a recursive function getFullPopulateObject that constructs a full population object for Strapi's query system. This function considers different field types such as components, dynamic zones, relations, and media.

```
  "use strict";

     const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::klubr.klubr", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const entity = await strapi.db.query("api::klubr.klubr").findOne({
      where: { slug: id },
      ...getFullPopulateObject("api::klubr.klubr"),
    });
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));

const { isEmpty, merge } = require("lodash/fp");

const getModelPopulationAttributes = (model) => {
  if (model.uid === "plugin::upload.file") {
    const { related, ...attributes } = model.attributes;
    return attributes;
  }

  return model.attributes;
};

const getFullPopulateObject = (modelUid, maxDepth = 20, parentModelUid = null) => {
  if (maxDepth <= 1) {
    return true;
  }
  if (modelUid === "admin::user") {
    return undefined;
  }

  const populate = {};
  const model = strapi.getModel(modelUid);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(
    getModelPopulationAttributes(model)
  )) {
    if (value) {
      if (value.type === "relation" && value.target === parentModelUid) {
        continue; 
      }
      if (value.type === "component") {
        populate[key] = getFullPopulateObject(value.component, maxDepth - 1);
      } else if (value.type === "dynamiczone") {
        const dynamicPopulate = value.components.reduce((prev, cur) => {
          const curPopulate = getFullPopulateObject(cur, maxDepth - 1);
          return curPopulate === true ? prev : merge(prev, curPopulate);
        }, {});
        populate[key] = isEmpty(dynamicPopulate) ? true : dynamicPopulate;
      } else if (value.type === "relation") {
        const relationPopulate = getFullPopulateObject(
          value.target,
          maxDepth - 1,
          modelUid // Pass the current model as parent
        );
        if (relationPopulate) {
          populate[key] = relationPopulate;
        }
      
        
      } else if (value.type === "media") {
        populate[key] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return isEmpty(populate) ? true : { populate };
};
```

This approach successfully populates all related fields in the findOne query. I hope this solution helps others working with custom controllers in Strapi.